# Redirect a URL in .htaccess, but keep the query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters, url-rewriting

I want to redirect a URL in .htaccess, but want to keep the (dynamic) parameters from the query string at the end of the URL (e.g. `?id=1660`, `?id=1661`, etc.)

E.g.
`https://mywebsite.example/service/viewinvoice.php?id=1660`

I want to redirect it to:

`https://mywebsite.example/whmcs-bridge/?ccce=viewinvoice.php?id=1660`

So basically: `https://mywebsite.example/service/viewinvoice.php?id=...` needs to be redirected to `https://mywebsite.example/whmcs-bridge/?ccce=viewinvoice.php?id=...`

I tried this below, without any success

```
 RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)/service/viewinvoice.php?id= [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /whmcs-bridge/?ccce=viewinvoice.php [L,R=301]
```

I think this is not the right solution.
Does someone has suggestions?

Comment: `/whmcs-bridge/?ccce=viewinvoice.php?id=1660` - you want to preserve the `?` so `viewinvoice.php?id=1660` is a single parameter value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [QSA](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) (Query String Append) flag on your rewrite rule.  From the documentation:

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

From your example URLs, you don't need to match the query string in a rewrite condition.  You are matching the URL path which is done as the first part of the rewrite rule itself.

Your rule should be:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?service/viewinvoice\.php$ /whmcs-bridge/?ccce=viewinvoice.php [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: Although this doesn’t actually do what the question is asking (unless there is a typo in the question)… it would append `id=1660` as a separate URL parameter ie. `ccce=viewinvoice.php&id=1660` rather than being part of the `ccce` parameter as they seem to require, ie. `ccce=viewinvoice.php?id=1660`

Comment: I was assuming there was a typo in the question, but you are correct.